Using Discord.py to extend audit logs
I want to create a Discord bot that will print information about who made changes in channel positions.
I tried to achieve this by using only:
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_update(before, after):
However, it does not contain any information about who made the update.
I also attempted to retrieve information from:
await guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_update)
But the audit logs do not include information about channel position changes.
Is it even possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

As far as I know, Discord itself (not just Discord.py) doesn't support channel position tracking yet. The event and those audit logs are primarily for tracking changes (with detailed info) in channel properties, not positions. Sadly, that's a limitation Discord currently has in its API, but that might change in the future.
